# Method works in one program but not the other

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm programming a solution to a problem, and I've run into an issue with the PIL image method.

```
choice = input("Would you like to save the maze as a file, Y/N?").upper()
if choice == "Y":
    canvas.update()
    canvas.postscript(file="maze.eps", colormode='color')
    img = Image.open("maze.eps")
```

However I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\NEA\Technical Solution\mazeVisualiser.py", line 66, in <module>
    img = Image.open("maze.eps")
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

But while learning the PIL module I know this is valid like so:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('brick-house.png')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has got me completely stuck.

Comment: Are you sure the `Image` in your `mazeVisualiser` script is actually the PIL.Image module? It could be worth checking whether the `import` statements are correct, and making sure you haven't accidentally assigned anything to a variable that also happens to be called Image.

Comment: I 100% don't have an Image variable, but this issue also doesn't allow me to save the eps file as a png either, which I know it should do from testing outside this program.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import PIL.Image

fp = open("brick-house.png", "rb")
img = PIL.Image.open(fp)
img.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This caused an error which was `OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths`

Comment: @MatthewPearce: try to install Ghostscript module by 'pip install Ghostscript' command.

Comment: The same issue still occurs, but I've discovered that this error message doesn't appear if the line `img.show()` isn't present.

Comment: @MatthewPearce: so... now is it ok? if it is plz vote it up.